# *** glibc detected *** ./parent_child_conscall: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x09d9e028 ***

Tags: c++

My code contains two classes.

```
  class points{
            char *p;
    public: points(){cout<<"constructor points called"<<endl;p=new char();}
            virtual ~points(){cout<<"destructor points called"<<endl;delete(p);}
  };
  class otherpoints: public points{
                    points x1;
    public: otherpoints(){cout<<"constructor otherpoints called"<<endl;x1=points();}
            ~otherpoints(){cout<<"destructor otherpoints called"<<endl;}
  };
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    otherpoints y1;

    return 0;
  }
```

Here I allocate a pointer in base class constructor and destroy memory of pointer in the respective base class destructor.

When I run the binary using valgrind, it gives error:-

```
constructor points called

constructor points called

constructor otherpoints called

constructor points called

destructor points called

destructor otherpoints called

destructor points called

==2209== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]

==2209==    at 0x4024851: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)

==2209==    by 0x8048A36: points::~points() (in home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==    by 0x8048BB2: otherpoints::~otherpoints() (in /home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==    by 0x804889A: main (in /home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==  Address 0x42d5098 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd

==2209==    at 0x4024851: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)

==2209==    by 0x8048A36: points::~points() (in /home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==    by 0x8048B32: otherpoints::otherpoints() (in /home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==    by 0x8048889: main (in /home/santosh/programs/c++/parent_child_conscall)

==2209==    destructor points called

==2209== 

==2209== HEAP SUMMARY:

==2209==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks

==2209==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 3 bytes allocated

==2209== 

==2209== LEAK SUMMARY:

==2209==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks

==2209==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2209==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2209==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2209==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==2209== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

==2209== 

==2209== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==2209== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 18 from 7)
```

**Unable to know which 1 byte memory I am unable to deallocate.**

Do I have to post the backtrace report?

Any help is thankful.

Comment: Read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: You need to give `points` an assignment operator and a copy constructor. Look up *the rule of three*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you create two instances of the `points` class. One temporary with `points()` and of course one with the declaration of `x1`.

When you do `x1 = points()` you create a temporary object with the `points()` construct, this is then copy-assigned to `x1`, and then the temporary object is destroyed. Since you do not provide a copy-assignment operator, the compiler will create one for you, but it simply copies the pointer, and don't allocate new memory. This means you for a while have two objects containing a pointer to the same memory. When the temporary object is destroyed you free the memory in the destructor, leaving the pointer in `x1` dangling. When `x1` is destroyed you try to delete this dangling pointer, leading to the double-free error.

The best way to solve this, is to implement a copy-assignment operator, and preferably a copy-constructor as well, and in those allocate new memory and copy the data.